# How to redirect different edit pages acording to table column values in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

in my laravel 5.6 app I have some edit pages to regarding different vehicle types. I need redirect them by cheching vehicles table categoryname values, my vehicle table as following,

```
id  name   model    year  categoryname  user_id
1   toyota  121     2001      car           1
2   nissan  sunney  1998      car           2
3   toyota  liteace 2000      van           5
4   isuzu   elf     2005      truck         9
5   bmw     520d    2010      car           7
```

this is edit and delete buttons links blade file,

```
<td><a class="button is-outlined" href="{{route('vehicles.edit',$vehicule->id.'/edit/')}}" >Edit</a></td>

                            <td><a class="button is-outlined" href="/myads/{{$vehicule->id}}/delete" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to want to delete this record?')" >Delete</a></td>
```

and route,

```
Route::get('myads/{id}/edit', [
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\VehicleController@edit',
    'as'=> 'vehicles.edit'
]);
```

now I have different edit blade file as caredit, vanedit, truckedit etc... in vechicles view file. there fore I need check vehicle table categoryname values and redirect them with suitable edit view file. How can do this?

Comment: Query the database. If the category is for car, return caredit, if van, return vanedit, ...

Comment: @FelippeDuarte could you explain by codes what did you mean

Answer (score 0):

if your blade names are  caredit, vanedit, truckedit, then you can do

```
return view($vehicule->categoryname . 'edit');
```

Comment: where should I put this?